# Removing the second "|" on the last position

Tags: r, regex, string

Here are some examples from my data:

```
a <-c("sp|Q9Y6W5|","sp|Q9HB90|,sp|Q9NQL2|","orf|NCBIAAYI_c_1_1023|",
     "orf|NCBIACEN_c_10_906|,orf|NCBIACEO_c_5_1142|", 
      "orf|NCBIAAYI_c_258|,orf|aot172_c_6_302|,orf|aot180_c_2_405|")
```

For a: The individual strings can contain even more entries of "sp|" and "orf"

The results have to be like this:

```
[1] "sp|Q9Y6W5" "sp|Q9HB90,sp|Q9NQL2" "orf|NCBIAAYI_c_1_1023" 
   "orf|NCBIACEN_c_10_906,orf|NCBIACEO_c_5_1142" 
   "orf|NCBIAAYI_c_258,orf|aot172_c_6_302,orf|aot180_c_2_405"
```

So the aim is to remove the last "|" for each "sp|" and "orf|" entry. It seems that "|" is a special challenge because it is a metacharacter in regular expressions. Furthermore, the length and composition of the "orf|" entries varying a lot. The only things they have in common is "orf|" or "sp|" at the beginning and that "|" is on the last position. I tried different things with gsub() but also with the stringr package or regexpr() or [:punct:], but nothing really worked. Maybe it was just the wrong combination.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub` to match the `|` that is followed by a `,` or is at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("[|](?=(,|$))", "", a, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "sp|Q9Y6W5" 
#[2] "sp|Q9HB90,sp|Q9NQL2"                                     
#[3] "orf|NCBIAAYI_c_1_1023" 
#[4] "orf|NCBIACEN_c_10_906,orf|NCBIACEO_c_5_1142"             
#[5] "orf|NCBIAAYI_c_258,orf|aot172_c_6_302,orf|aot180_c_2_405"
```

---

Or we `split` by `,', remove the last character with`substr`, and`paste`the`list` elements together

```
sapply(strsplit(a, ","), function(x) paste(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1), collapse=","))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your suggestion worked absolutely perfect. I better keep going to increase my knowledge regarding regular expressions and how to use them.:-)

Answer (score 0):

An easy alternative that might work. You need to escape the "`|`" using "`\\|`".

```
# Input
a <-c("sp|Q9Y6W5|","sp|Q9HB90|,sp|Q9NQL2|","orf|NCBIAAYI_c_1_1023|",
      "orf|NCBIACEN_c_10_906|,orf|NCBIACEO_c_5_1142|", 
      "orf|NCBIAAYI_c_258|,orf|aot172_c_6_302|,orf|aot180_c_2_405|")

# Expected output
b <- c("sp|Q9Y6W5", "sp|Q9HB90,sp|Q9NQL2", "orf|NCBIAAYI_c_1_1023" ,
       "orf|NCBIACEN_c_10_906,orf|NCBIACEO_c_5_1142" ,
       "orf|NCBIAAYI_c_258,orf|aot172_c_6_302,orf|aot180_c_2_405")

res <- gsub("\\|,", ",", gsub("\\|$", "", a))

all(res == b)
#[1] TRUE
```

You could construct a single regex call to `gsub`, but this is simple and easy to understand. The inner `gsub` looks for `|` and the end of the string and removes it. The outer `gsub` looks for `,|` and replaces with `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use a PCRE regex here as all you need can be done with the default TRE regex (if you specify `perl=TRUE`, the pattern is compiled with a PCRE regex engine and is sometimes slower than TRE default regex engine).

Here is the single simple `gsub` call:

```
gsub("\\|(,|$)", "\\1", a)
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/q6evKb). No lookarounds are really necessary, as you see.

**Pattern details**

- `\\|` - a literal `|` symbol (because if you do not escape it or put into a bracket expression it will denote an alternation operator, see the line below)
- `(,|$)`  - a *capturing group* (referenced to with `\1` from the replacement pattern) matching either of the two alternatives:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `|` - or (the alternation operator)
  - `$` - end of string anchor.

The `\1` in the replacement string tells the regex engine to insert the contents stored in the capturing group #1 back into the resulting string (so, the commas are restored that way where necessary).